# Creating customer_id based on matchcodes in Oracle (SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, matching, consolidation

I have an oracle database containing purchases of customers. (one record is one purchase) Customers provided their personal data again and again at every purchase. So there can be differences due to mistype, address change, etc. Now I have to identify purchases belonging to the same customer.

To do that I created 3 different match code based on simple rules. My table looks somehow like this now:

```
  
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| PURCACHE_ID | MATCHCODE_1 | MATCHCODE_2 | MATCHCODE_3 | CUSTOMER_ID |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|             |             |             |             |             |
| 1           | 1           | b           | x           |             |
|             |             |             |             |             |
| 2           | 1           | a           | y           |             |
|             |             |             |             |             |
| 3           | 2           | c           | x           |             |
|             |             |             |             |             |
| 4           | 3           | a           | z           |             |
|             |             |             |             |             |
| ...         | ...         | ...         | ...         | ...         |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

What I want to do is to assign a customer_id to every purchase. Same customer_id would be assigned to purchases where any matchcode equals to another one.

So for example purchase 1 and purchase 2 would receive the same customer_id because matchcode 1 is the same.  Also purchase 2 and purchase 4 belong to the same customer cause Matchcode_2 is the same. Thereby even purchase 1 and purchase 4 would receive the same customer_id though none of their matchcodes equals.

Customer_id can be a simple number starting from 1.

What is the SQL code to make Customer_Id?

Comment: This is very risky, because you may end up with conflicting data.  From your example we can infer that matchcode 3 will always be the same customer as matchcode 1 and matchcode z will always be the same customer as matchcode x and y and matchcode a will always be the same customer as matchcode b. The solution to that is to provide priority rules to determine which matchcode matches take precedence.  e.g. cellphone number is a better match than address, since multiple customers *could* live at one address.

Comment: It's not a problem for me. To illustrate it with a simplified example matchcode 1 is created from Name and Adresse while matchcode 2 is from Name and Phone Number. Customer had phone number A and lived on place X and made a purchase. Then he moved to place Y and made a purchase again. He changed his phone number to B and made a purchase again. In this case purchase 3 will have different matchcode 1 and matchcode 2 than purchase 1 but I still know it was the same customer. I can imagine some special case when it can be a problem but it is only for analytic purposes so I can live with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A naive solution:

```
-- Just number them
UPDATE purchases SET customer_id = rownum;

-- Group all customers with given matchcode_1 into one
MERGE INTO purchases p
USING (SELECT matchcode_1, min(customer_id) customer_id
         FROM purchases
    GROUP BY matchcode_1) m
ON (p.matchcode_1 = m.matchcode_1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET p.customer_id = m.customer_id;

-- Repeat the above merge for matchcode_2, matchcode_3
-- then matchcode_1 again and so on
-- until none of the matchcodes make any updates
```

You could write something nicer with PL/SQL probably...

Comment: Thanks! It seems like a viable solution though a little difficult to automate since we don't know the necessary number of repetitions. I assume I have to check at the end of every update the number of updates. After 3 consecutive update with 0 modifications I can finish.